# Lubuntu 20.04, Nvidia drivers installed, yet NVIDIA-SMI states it can't connect to driver

Tags: 20.04, gpu-driver, nvidia-settings

I followed the additional drivers prompt to install nvidia 440 drivers, they do show as installed. However the SMI output shows that it can't connect and acts as if it is either not installed or not running. prime-select query shows it is set to nvidia and i did attempt to swap the prime select to intel and then back to nvidia and ran a full reboot without any fix to the problem.

dpkg output for nvidia shows I have everything.

```
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-440:amd64                                    440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-440                                        440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-compute-440:amd64                                 440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-440:i386                                  440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-440:amd64                                  440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-440:i386                                   440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-440:amd64                                  440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-440:i386                                   440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-extra-440:amd64                                   440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        Extra libraries for the NVIDIA driver
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-440:amd64                                    440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-440:i386                                     440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-440:amd64                                      440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-440:i386                                       440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-440:amd64                                    440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-440:i386                                     440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-440                                    440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-dkms-440                                             440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-440                                           440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-440                                    440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-440                                    440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                                                0.8.14                                all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                                             440.64-0ubuntu1                       amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-440                                            440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  screen-resolution-extra                                     0.18build1                            all          Extension for the nvidia-settings control panel
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-440                               440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

On attempting to run nvidia-settings I get

```
ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded

ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system

(nvidia-settings:1791): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 01:18:05.602: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

Comment: How did you install the drivers?

Comment: I installed via the additional drivers utility GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Spent a while researching this before asking but I determined the best methodology was likely going to be purging all nvidia driver files via

```
sudo apt remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'
```

and then following CLI installation

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440
```

Once this was complete I ran `nvidia-settings` again and actually got the desired output rather than piles of errors stating the driver could not be found.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+                                                                                                              
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.100      Driver Version: 440.100      CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2060    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   51C    P5    14W /  N/A |    467MiB /  5934MiB |     23%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: `sudo apt install --reinstall nvidia-driver-440` also works.

Comment: Tried on ubuntu 20.10 and the same. Something strange with nvidia here.